# Quartile formula Multiple IFs across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel-formula

I was hoping to get some assistance with a formula I have. I am trying to calculate the second quartile (using multiple if statements) for a specific column across 2 worksheets. Alternatively, I could copy and paste the data into the one worksheet, but I am trying to avoid this.

This is the formula I have thus far:

```
=QUARTILE(IF((CHOOSE({1;2},'Table 2a'!A:A,'Table 2b'!A:A)=C2)*
(CHOOSE({1;2},'Table 2a'!L:L,'Table 2b'!L:L)=D24),CHOOSE({1;2},
'Table 2a'!BB:BB,'Table 2b'!BB:BB)),2)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do it on two separate sheets like that.  The data will need to be in the same sheet.  Unless you want to use vba.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I appreciate your input. I was able to produce QUARTILE results across the two worksheets initially but the formula seems to be failing when I add in the IF statements.

Comment: exactly, you can do a 3d quartile if it is not an array formula.